# Getting data from JSON using RxJS trying to return array and pass values to different behavior subjects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, nativescript, behaviorsubject

First, I am open to other things besides behavior subjects? but this is what is working for me so far.  I have a Nativescript app using the Latest Angular7 build and Nativescript 5.1  I am trying to populate a ListView in NS with a json file and its all working good so far.  But I would like to do more with the config file than just the initial listview.

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { IMenuItem } from "~/app/menuItem";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class DataItemService {

  items$ = new BehaviorSubject<Array<IMenuItem>>([]);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  clear(): void {
    this.items$.next([]);
  }

  fetch(): Observable<any> {

    this.clear();

    return this.http.get("https://example.com/config.json")
      .pipe(
        map((data) => {
          return (data["result"]) ? data["result"] : false;
          }
        ),
        tap((items) => { if (items) { this.items$.next(items); }}),
        catchError((err) => {
          return of(false);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

My question goes like this.  Using the code above I am getting a portion of my array in the "result" section.  But I would also like to get config as well and save it.   Is there a way for me to do the exact same thing I am doing with data["results"] and save it to this.config$ intstead of this.items$

I'd like both objects from the same json but not have to do 2 calls to set it all up.  Is there a way I can do 1 call to the JSON and then save off the different objects as behavior subjects ?

```
{
 "config": [
     {
     "debug": true
     }
 ],
 "result": [
   {
     "id": 0,
     "title": "Home",
     "titleFontSize": 16,
     "iconFontSize": 30,
     "subtitle": "This is the subtitle for messages",
     "image": "",
     "icon": "fa-home",
     "url": "/home",
     "sidebar": true,
     "mainmenu": false,
     "bg": "#ffdc00",
     "titleColor": "white",
     "subtitleColor": "white",
     "squarebg": "rgba(0,0,0,.8)"
  }
 ]
}
```

--- EDIT ---

using the answer as inspiration from below.. i have this

```
fetch(): Observable<any> {

this.clear();

return this.http.get("https://example.com/config.json")
  .pipe(
    tap(({start, finish}) => {
  if (start) {
    this.items$.next(start);
    console.log("ITEMS ARE   " + JSON.stringify(this.items$.value));
  }
  if (finish) {
    this.config$.next(finish);
    console.log("CONFIG IS   " + JSON.stringify(this.config$.value));

  }
}
));
```

Now I modified my JSON to have 2 keys.  start and finish (because config was complaining that it was already used in some other dependency).  so with start and finish in my JSON I do console.log and I get both the keys.. start and finish.

the new issue is that my original call had a MAP which removed all the other crap and just gave me the array with no observable code.   the new stuff gives me a bunch of observable content with it..  my current ListView doesn't populate now with the new code even though I know console log is doing what we want (mostly).

```
<RadListView [items]="items$ | async"

    ngOnInit() {
       this._dataItemService.fetch().subscribe();

       this.items$  = this._dataItemService.items$;
    }
```

Comment: It is not good practice to continue editing the same question. If you got an answer to your original question, you should accept it. If you have a followup question, post it as a distinct question. StackOverflow isn't meant as an iterative "help" forum.

Comment: thanks for your concerns! :)  its actually solved from the first question i was just explaining the first issue syntax was too big for a comment so StackOverflow told me to edit my post..  wasn't  my idea ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the map in between, you can extract data with ES6 syntax.

```
this.http.get("https://example.com/config.json")
      .pipe(
         tap(({result,config})) => { 
if (result) this.items$.next(items); 
if (config) this.config$.next(config); 
}),
        catchError((err) => {
          return of(false);
        })
      );
```

Comment: gettin some syntax issues, trying to work around it but its not goin atm

Comment: ok fixed syntax. workin on implementing it. will keep you posted

Comment: why is that.? have you console.log and check the result return from http?

Comment: The code looks good, if you still have issues please share a Playground sample which we may be able to fix it for you.

Comment: for starters, it complains step 1 just pasting it in becuase it says the code is unreachable.   says there is a , or a ) missing after TAP   is it written correctly? do we have too many parenthesis?  if i start removing parentheis to fix syntax then from there it doesn't work, if i leave it, it throws syntax errors so i need to fix either the above code to get it to read or something is wrong.  thats issue 1, issue 2 is..  how does result and config have anything to do with the json?  how does that magically split my json into 2 files based on that key? maybe that part will work after fix?

Comment: ok I updated my original question with the NEW code that I am using.. console.log looks good but the ListView needs some modifications to get the new code??

Comment: its solved, thanks.. listView was fine.. i just needed to pass my data in the order that the JSON has the keys.. so config first / items second.. after swapping it to match my listview started populating.  thanks  I did have to remove 1 parenthesis after your tap (({results, config} )

Answer (score 0):

You're throwing away observable chaining here by breaking out a secondary subject, but that is a discussion for another time, I suppose.

To follow the paradigm that you're already using, you can just `.subscribe` and use it elsewhere. In whichever context is calling the `fetch`, you can attach to the result of that and process it as the end of the chain, if you like.

```
config: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

constructor(private dataItemService: DataItemService) {
}

fetch(): void {
  this.dataItemService.fetch().subscribe((items: any) => {
    this.config$.next(items);
  });
}
```

---

You should be aware that your `.pipe` will get executed for each subscriber, and also any "termination" point should be its own subscriber. As it is right now, you've got a side-effect happening here that will push a new value to `items$` for each thing that subscribes.

That is, if you do:

```
let obs: Observable<any> = this.dataItemService.fetch();
obs.subscribe((items) => this.config$.next(items));
obs.subscribe((items) => this.otherConfig$.next(items));
```

You'll get `items$` within `dataItemService` pushed with the same value twice because it is in a `.pipe` chain that leads to each `.subscribe`. Instead, you might consider breaking that assignment out as its own `.subscribe` *or* putting in a `pipe(share())` to make sure that all pipes are compressed prior to the final notification to all subscribers.

```
fetch(): Observable<any> {
  this.clear();

  let obs$: Observable<any> = this.http.get("https://example.com/config.json")
    .pipe(map((data) => (data["result"]) ? data["result"] : false ))
    .pipe(share())    // Processes 'data' only once, returning the same result to each subscriber
    catchError((err) => {
      return of(false);
    })
  );
  obs$.subscribe((items) => this.items$.next(items));

  return obs$;
}
```